# Does the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{x^3 - x^2}$ exist or not?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, limits-without-lhopital, epsilon-delta

I am having some arguments with a friend about the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{x^3 - x^2}$$

FACTS: the domain of the function is $x\in \{0\}\cup [1,\ +\infty)$ and $0$ is an isolated point.

My friend says the limit doesn't exist, whilst to me it is $0$. Who is right?

In my opinion, if we take $\epsilon > 0$ and $\delta = 1/2$, we calculate $|f(x) - f(0)| < 0$ hence less than $\epsilon$, so for any positive $\epsilon$ we have positive $\delta$ such that whenever $x$ is in $\delta$-neighbourhood of $0$, the quantity $|f(x) - f(0)|$ is less than $\epsilon$ so $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Am I right or wrong?

Can someone pease make a limpid clarification of the existence (or not) of this limit?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the definition of limit that you are working with?

Comment: From this question, I learned a new word: limpid. Never knew of that word before.

Comment: The definition that I was taught was that if $D$ is the domain of a function $f(x)$, then $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L ~\iff$$  $$\forall \epsilon > 0, ~\exists \delta > 0 ~\text{such that}~ $$ $$\{0 < |x - a| < \delta ~\text{and}~ x \in D\} \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon.$$  Since $0$ is an isolated point, the assertion will be vacuously true for any value $L$.  The problem here is that I have never been exposed to the situation where a function could have more than one limit, as $x$ approached $(x=0)$.  So, I question how you are supposed to interpret the issue when $0$ is an isolated point.

Comment: I think in order to talk (meaningfully) about limits, you need to ask that 0 is an *accumulation point* of the domain of $f$ as @user2661923 points out. What you've shown is that $f$ is *continuous* at 0, which is a different matter.

Comment: @Jose27: no need for that. The classical [definition](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Limit#The_limit_of_a_function_.28mapping.29.), as introduced by Weierstrass is as user2661923. That definition carries out even to topological spaces (with some minimal separability assumptions) In that context, then accumulation points and all that Jazz becomes important.

Comment: On $D=\{0\}\cup[1,\infty)$ the map $f:x\mapsto\sqrt{x^3-x^2}$ is well defined. Notice also the for any $\varepsilon>0$ and $0<a<\min(1,\varepsilon^2/4)$ we have that  $x\in D$ and  $0<|x-0|<1+a:=\delta$ implies that  is for $|f(x)-0|<|x|\sqrt{x-1}<\varepsilon$.  Thus, the limit in the OP exists and is $0$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If we go by the standard definition at an isolated point, the function will have any limit (since we get to choose $\delta$ small enough so that the punctured neighborhood is always disjoint from the domain). It seems as if what you're doing is "almost-identifying" $\{ 0\}$ and $\{ 1\}$ and treating a limit in this new space, but in my opinion that's a different thing than taking the limit in $D$, **as a subset of** $\mathbb{R}$, of the function given.

Comment: @Jose27: The $\varepsilon>0$ is choses as small as you want, the $\delta>0$ depends on $\varepsilon$. So, as long as $0<|x-0|<\delta_\varepsilon$ and $x\in D$, one has that $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$,

Comment: @OliverDíaz: I agree, and if we choose $\delta=\min\{ 1, \delta_\epsilon\}$, then any $L$ will fulfill the condition, not just $L=0$.

Comment: @Jose27: $L=0$ in the OP, and  $\delta_\varepsilon=1+\min(1,\varepsilon^2/4)$ does the job: If $x\in\{0\}\cup[1,\infty)$ and $0<|x-0|<\delta_\varepsilon$, then $|f(x)-L|=f(x)=x\sqrt{x-1}<\varepsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, any answer will depend on exactly which definition of a limit you are using. As was pointed out in the comments, one usually doesn't take limits at isolated points in the domain. From a definitions perspective, one could argue that that **ANY** limit is vacuously the limit of the function at $0$ although perhaps that's not very helpful in an argument with your friend. Perhaps it would be more enlightening to expand the domain of the function to include complex numbers as this will indeed give you the limit of zero. Consider the transformation $z=re^{i\theta}$. Then for small enough $r$ we have

$$|\sqrt{z^3-z^2}|=|z|\sqrt{z-1}=r\left|\sqrt{re^{i\theta}-1}\right|\leq 2r$$

Thus

$$0\leq\lim_{z\to 0}|\sqrt{z^3-z^2}|=\lim_{r\to 0^+}r\left|\sqrt{re^{i\theta}-1}\right|\leq \lim_{r\to 0^+}2r=0$$

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about delta-epsilon proof, but I know a different way to compute the limit. $$\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{x^3 - x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{x^2( x-1)}$$ Now if $x\to 0^+$ or $x\to 0^-$, in both of these cases, $(x-1)$ will be negative and hence, both, left-hand as well as right-hand limits are undefined. As a result, the overall limit doesn't exist.

Comment: This is not (generally speaking) correct.  You need to define what you mean by a limit before you can give a definitive answer.